# Could Maven upload my source code to Central without my authorization?

Tags: security, maven, repository

From this [article](http://happygiraffe.net/blog/tag/maven/), I learned that Maven uses a central place to hold open source code for solving dependency problem. This is a very convenient feature. However, if I use Maven to build some project, will it upload my source code to somewhere on Internet even without my authorization?

Last time when I tried to build something like `my-secret-service.jar` with a group ID `com.notarealgroup`, executing `mvn install` gave some output like this:

```
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/notarealgroup/my-secret-service/1.0/my-secret-service-1.0.jar
```

This is very confusing to me: How could this `my-secret-service-1.0.jar` be found at [repository.jboss.org](http://repository.jboss.org) ? It should not been there (and is indeed not there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference a library, maven searches for it in the local repo, then, by default, it will search the public repositories. It isn't uploading your jar, but there is still a security concern with it passing the name of the jar to the online repo. If you're very paranoid (my current employers *are* that paranoid) then you want to stop this, and to do that you'll have to read the maven documentation. However, rest assured, unless you choose to deploy your stuff to a public maven repo, which isn't trivial to achieve anyway, it'll not happen by accident.

Answer (score 0):

**No, Maven won't to do that, for any sensible definition of "authorization".**

For your artifact to be uploaded to e.g. Central, you'd need:

- Central set as as your upload repository in `distributionManagement` (there's no default setting in the [SuperPOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM)),
- your environment set for correct upload authorization for Central (in your settings.xml or otherwise),
- you, explicitly or implicitly, launching a deployment, the arguably easiest way being through running the `deploy` phase.

*None* of those requirements can be derived from Maven's default configuration, especially when just running `mvn install`. At worst, you'd need to set a specifically crafted project as a parent for anything "unwanted" to happen. **When in doubt, check your [effective POM](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html)**.

In either case, it's not so easy for just anyone to upload any artifact to Central - if it was, we'd be up to here in maliciously constructed artifacts.

As Engineer Dollery mentioned in his answer, the message you're seeing is Maven simply attempting to **download** a dependency, which happens to be identified by your custom coordinates (`groupId`, `artifactId`). And this brings us to your final question which I'll answer with another question - why *couldn't* it be there? It's just an artifact, after all.

Comment: And it says only `Downloading`: in more words `Trying to download`. If it would succeed, it would also have said `Downloaded`.

Comment: @RobertScholte: exactly, hence "attempting to download" :).